# Nested comments pagination will not work for children comments

Tags: php, mysql

**Hard limit is working thanks to Luuk, but pagination is still not working.**

Based on my previous question, I am currently building comments system for a blog and want to make it reddit like.

I am currently using the nested comments by http://www.jongales.com/blog/2009/01/27/php-class-for-threaded-comments/

```
class Threaded_comments  
{  
      
    public $parents  = array();  
    public $children = array();  
  
    /** 
     * @param array $comments  
     */  
    function __construct($comments)  
    {  
        foreach ($comments as $comment)  
        {  
            if ($comment['parent_id'] === NULL)  
            {  
                $this->parents[$comment['id']][] = $comment;  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                $this->children[$comment['parent_id']][] = $comment;  
            }  
        }          
    }  
     
    /** 
     * @param array $comment 
     * @param int $depth  
     */  
    private function format_comment($comment, $depth)  
    {     
        for ($depth; $depth > 0; $depth--)  
        {  
            echo "\t";  
        }  
          
        echo $comment['text'];  
        echo "\n";  
    }  
      
    /** 
     * @param array $comment 
     * @param int $depth  
     */   
    private function print_parent($comment, $depth = 0)  
    {     
        foreach ($comment as $c)  
        {  
            $this->format_comment($c, $depth);  
  
            if (isset($this->children[$c['id']]))  
            {  
                $this->print_parent($this->children[$c['id']], $depth + 1);  
            }  
        }  
    }  
  
    public function print_comments()  
    {  
        foreach ($this->parents as $c)  
        {  
            $this->print_parent($c);  
        }  
    }  
    
}
```

Here’s the example usage with the data provided as an array. Remember that if your data is in another format you’ll have to modify the class.

```
$comments = array(  array('id'=>1, 'parent_id'=>NULL,   'text'=>'Parent'),  
                    array('id'=>2, 'parent_id'=>1,      'text'=>'Child'),  
                    array('id'=>3, 'parent_id'=>2,      'text'=>'Child Third level'),  
                    array('id'=>4, 'parent_id'=>NULL,   'text'=>'Second Parent'),  
                    array('id'=>5, 'parent_id'=>4,   'text'=>'Second Child')  
                );  
  
$threaded_comments = new Threaded_comments($comments);  
  
$threaded_comments->print_comments();
```

Example Output:

```
Parent
    Child
        Child Third level
Second Parent
    Second Child
```

I have set the depth limit, created the html output and everything, but the problem is pagination. Whenever I try to do a pagination via offset limit, **it disrupts the child comments and the structure** because the next page does not have original parent where to attach children and such.

For example:

```
select count(*) as found_comments from comments where blog_post = 1 and parent_id is null;
result = 20; // lets say its 20 parent comments limit from query above.

    $query = "select * from comments where blog_post = 1 LIMIT 0,20";

    $comments = [];
    foreach ($query as $row)
    {
    $comments[] = [
'id' => $row['id'], 
'parent_id' => $row['parent_id'], 
'text' = $row['text'], 
'added' => $row['added']];
    }

$threaded_comments = new Threaded_comments($comments);  
  
$threaded_comments->print_comments();
```

This code will limit both parent and children comments, but I need to set it to limit only parents, so 20 parents per page.

If I set in count query `WHERE blog_post = 1 AND parent_id = 0`
it will count parents only, **but will cut out children comments when 20 quota** is reached in `$comments` query.

It's really headache to find a way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of how to change your code to only print 2 parents:

```
public function print_comments($count =2)  
{  
    foreach ($this->parents as $c)  
    {  
        $this->print_parent($c);  
        $count--;
        if($count == 0) exit;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Woah, this is amazing and such a simple solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh, but the problem is now pagination. I still need to set offset limit in $comments query so I can paginate and if I set it there, it still cut comments.

Comment: what do you want to do it only part of a thread fits? Will you print that part, and continue the next page where you left? Or anything else?   Too many variations exists to give 1 solution.

Comment: For example we limit 10 parents, it will print all children to those 10 parents and on next page will give next 10 parents with all their children and so on. I guess the $comments query must be inside the class

PS: thats all for a single blog post.

Comment: Here is example query `$limit = 10; $offset = $_GET['page']; $query = SELECT * FROM comments WHERE blog_post = 1 LIMIT $offest, $limit`, Now `foreach($query as $row) { $comments[] = ['id' => $row['id'], 'parent_id' => $row['parent_id'], 'text' => $row['text']];}`

Comment: Sorry, English is not my primary language, what suc6 means? Thank you for helping me this far, if you have any idea on how to approach this offset for parent limiting please suggest me how to approach it when you have a time. Thank you in advance

Comment: sorry, English is not my primary language too but i meant to say "Succes"

Comment: Thanks :) You told me about many variations, what was your idea of doing it. If you could edit the main answer so I can fiddle and play with that. This is the third day im having trouble sorting those things out. Heh. Anyway I will put comment as solved as I dont think anyone else will contribute to it.